# Фильтры и хуки для Woocommerce. Перенести описание

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Всех приветсвую! Подскажите мне как перенести описание товара под категории?

Имеем стандартный шаблон карточки товара (single-product.php)
Он выглядит так:
[image: Стандартный шаблон]

Мне нужно удалить блок в нижней части карточки, где расположены табы и перенести его под отображение категории с правой стороны, то-есть чтоб он был справа от фотографии, показал на скриншоте снизу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле `functions.php` вашей темы:

1. удаляете табы с хука `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`:

```php
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10);
```

2. цепляете их на хук `woocommerce_single_product_summary`:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 70);
```